Formulation of Axioms about Landau Big $O$ and Small $o$ Notation Arithmetics
My question is, how to evaluate and prove the situation when we have something like , say $o[\frac1{2x}+o(\frac 1x)]=o[\frac 1x]$.
In which I encountered this case while calculating the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left[\frac 1e-\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x\right]$$
And as I haven't found a comprehensive question involving the arithmetic of landau symbols, can you offer a generalization (Axiomization) for arithmetics of Big $O$ and small $o$?
Including Composites of them (resp. mixed and single), addition and subtraction of them, exponential of them, and so on. And if you think a book would be suitable for this question, what is it?

Unsolicited feedback: people are liable to get upset if you ask four questions in one post. Further, an answer to your first question can probably easily be found on the Wikipedia or any number of websites or books.

Thanks @Novice, I will edit

Taking formal definition, for example, for little $o$ we can imagine $o(f)$ as set of functions like $\varepsilon \cdot f$, where $\varepsilon \to 0$. So, for your first example $o[\frac1{2x}+o(\frac 1x)]$ is functions like $\varepsilon (x)\cdot [\frac1{2x}+o(\frac 1x)] = \frac 1x \varepsilon_1(x)$, where $\varepsilon_1 \to 0$.

So are there any axioms related to the calculation of landau notations, or/and can you elucidate the formal definition of Landau Big O symbol to me, thx.

We called it definition, not axioms, which you can see on, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, or in Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein - Introduction to Algorithms-The MIT Press (2022), page 54. All properties for big-O comes from definition. For example $O(f)+O(g)=O(f+g)$. Same situation with little-o.
